# No custom principal is specified? [including sample]

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, iis-7, principal

When trying to run a method on my WCF service I get the following exception :

> No custom principal is specified in the authorization context.

I have tried to extract the `IIdentity` in `CustomAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate` but there is none?

Please check this sample out :

https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6176678_9623043_31520313

The service is a WAS (TCP in IIS7) and you will probably need to host the service in IIS7 to get it running.

When that's done, all you need to do is run the project (client and service) and hit the button in the form.

Comment: Did you already google that error message? There seem to be a few answers out there floating around. Why didn't they work for you?

Comment: Exacly, I have been googling it and the solution I found is to set the Principal in CustomAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate but there is no Identities to fetch from the evaluationContext object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sercurity=none means that there is no principal created so this have to be done manualy.